# Wrong getCameraPosition on google-map if the device has soft (virtual) navigation button?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, virtual

I experience getting wrong `getCameraPosition` if the device has soft/virtual navigation buttons where the program is running on.
I use for test the below code.
(When the map is ready it adds a marker to `lng=0` `lat=0`, moves the camera there then writes the camera position to LogCat. 
Then if user tap the marker the program moves the camera to the marker-position then gets and writes the actual camera-position.)

The strange behavior is:

1. If I run the test on emulator everything are OK, camera moves to `lng=0`, `lat=0` and if I tap the marker I get back that 0;0 position as it should be.
2. if I run the test on Galaxy TAB Active 2 which has physical navigation buttons everything are OK, same as on emulator.
3. BUT if I run the test on Samsung Galaxy A50 which has no physical navigation buttons just soft/virtual ones the result is wrong. When I tap the marker I get back wrong latitude value which is 0.03348201322727862  NOT zero as it should be.
   Also this wrong value is changing with zoom level....(seems to be google-map does not calculate the space needed for soft buttons...?)

If I set the device  Display - Navigation bar to "Full screen gestures" opposite "Navigation buttons" then the above described behavior is disappearing and `getCameraPosition` results the expected value (0;0).

**Questions**:
 1. has somebody experienced the same behavior?
 2. can somebody do the test on other device with virtual navigation buttons?
 3. somebody knows solution or any workaround other than set the device to Full screen gestures?

Thank you

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
    mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    // Add a marker 
    LatLng origin = new LatLng(0, 0);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin).title("Origo"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin));

    //for test:
    CameraPosition cp=mMap.getCameraPosition();
    Double lat = cp.target.latitude;
    Double lng = cp.target.longitude;
    Log.i("cam","lat= "+Double.toString(lat)+" lon= "+Double.toString(lng));

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {


            LatLng p=marker.getPosition();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(p));

            CameraPosition cp=mMap.getCameraPosition();
            Double lat = cp.target.latitude;
            Double lng = cp.target.longitude;
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
            Log.i("cam","lat after marker is clicked... lat= "+Double.toString(lat)+" lon= "+Double.toString(lng));

            return true;
        }
        });

}

On emulator:
2019-12-21 23:02:15.866 29689-29689/com.xxxxxx.maptest I/cam: lat= 0.0 lon= 0.0
2019-12-21 23:02:28.794 29689-29689/com.xxxxxx.maptest I/cam: lat after marker is clicked = 0.0 lon= 0.0

On SAMSUNG A50:
2019-12-21 23:05:23.055 5594-5594/com.xxxxxx.maptest I/cam: lat= 0.0 lon= 0.0
2019-12-21 23:05:39.766 5594-5594/com.xxxxxx.maptest I/cam: lat after marker is clicked... **lat= 0.03348201322727862** lon= 0.0

On Samsung Galaxy TAB Active2:
2019-12-21 23:10:33.713 17999-17999/com.xxxxxx.maptest I/cam: lat= 0.0 lon= 0.0
2019-12-21 23:10:37.824 17999-17999/com.xxxxxx.maptest I/cam: lat after marker is clicked... lat= 0.0 lon= 0.0
```

Comment: I have tried to hide navigation bar but no result.

``` //hide navigation bar
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY); ` ` `

Comment: I have found a workaround (although I haven't got a clue why it is working):
If I add  

             ` mMap.setPadding(0,0,0,1);   //1 pixel bottom padding of map`

to onMapReady()  then the issue is disappear. I get good camera position independently of soft or hard navigation buttons on the device.
Would somebody explain why is this working? Thanks.